# Read from AsyncStorage, Parse Array, Convert String to Date object

Tags: javascript, react-native, parsing, setstate, asyncstorage

I'm trying to read array from Async storage with "reminders" key.

Problem is JSON.parse cannot convert 'time' key of element in Array to Date object.

I need to read from storage, parse and assign to reminders state using setReminders()

```
// EXAMPLE DATA IN ASYNC STORAGE
[{day: 'Monday', time: '2020-04-03T15:17:07.554Z', status: false},
{day: 'Friday', time: '2020-04-03T15:17:07.951Z', status: true},]


// LOAD REMINDERS
  useEffect(readReminders, []);

  function readReminders() {
   AsyncStorage.getItem('reminders').then(value =>setReminders(value));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can parse Date from string using `Date.parse(string)` or `new Date(string)` like:

```js
function readReminders() {
   AsyncStorage.getItem('reminders').then(values => {
      const reminders = values.map(item => {
         return {
           ...item,
           time: new Date(item.time)
         }
      });
   });
}
```

Comment: I have to use "setReminders" function to assign value to reminders state.
setReminders([....])

I cannot directly assign like
const reminders = [...]

Comment: Your solution giving error below:

Fri Apr 03 2020 19:40:48.670]  WARN     Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0):
TypeError: values.map is not a function. (In 'values.map(function (item) {
          return _objectSpread({}, item, {
            time: new Date(item.time)
          });
        })', 'values.map' is undefined)

Answer (score 1):

I have add the same issue with the date . try using moment instead of new Date()... 
'npm install moment
`import moment from "moment";
 const time= '2020-04-03T15:17:07.554Z';
 const todate= moment(time);`

Hope this will help.